# Rails: display assets from one model in another

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am building a rails app that has two models sites and equipment.

I want to display items of equipment on the site that they belong too.

So if a user creates a site named "site a" then creates a piece of equipment that belongs to "site a" it would be displayed on "site a" #show page.

I realize this might be quite basic and if you want to point me towards the right terms or articles or website or tutorial please do.

All relationships, forms and views are set up. thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your Site model looks like this:

```
class Site < ApplicationModel
  has_many :equipment
end
```

then on the site show page, you can do:

```
<% @site.equipment.each do |equipment| %>
  <p><%= equipment.name %></p>
<% end %>
```

Comment: thanks @jimmybaker I think my model for assigning the data to the site is flawed and where the problem is